# Getting images into Tableau?

Tags: graph, tableau-api

Does anyone have a good guide or how-to list for getting images into Tableau? I'm creating a data visualization about covid-19 tweet sentiments and would like to add images of certain milestones of the pandemic (e.g. first vaccine goes into trial, first vaccine approved, global case count reaches X, etc.).

My goal is that when people hover over certain time periods of the sentiment graph, an image and title pops up about various milestones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add them to your shapes folder.
https://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2016/2/how-use-custom-shapes-filters-your-dashboard-50200